# Element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to loop over the elements and click at them. At each click it goes to the new page, then I want to go back and click at the next element but then it raises an error cause the element is stale. I can declare an index variable and increase it over each iteration then refresh the page, find those elements again and access them by index, but what is the most efficient way to resolve this?

```
links = link_grid.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div:nth-child(1)")
            
for link in links:
       link.click()
       sleep(1)
       driver.back()
       sleep(1)
```

Comment: You have to find the elements again when the page has been refreshed.

Comment: If you have to refresh the page, then the element has gone 'stale' and you need to find it again. If an element changes in any way from the time it's found to the time it's interacted with, selenium will say it's a stale element. Basically meaning that it found it originally, but it's no longer there where it found it originally. Best practice for selenium is to find the element right before you interact with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By navigating to another page all collected by selenium web elements (they are actually references to a physical web elements) become no more valid since the web page is re-built when you open it again.
To make your code working you need to collect the `links` list again each time.
This should work:

```py
links = link_grid.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div:nth-child(1)")
            
for link in links:
    link.click()
    sleep(1)
    driver.back()
    links = link_grid.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div:nth-child(1)")
```